# Modelling a Kafka cluster

Tags: apache-kafka

I have an API endpoint that accepts events with a specific user ID and some other data. I want those events broadcasted to some external locations and I wanted to explore using Kafka as a solution for that.

I have the following requirements:

1. Events with the same `UserID` should be delivered in order to the external locations.
2. Events should be persisted.
3. If a single external location is failing, that shouldn't delay delivery to other locations.

Initially, from some reading I did, it felt like I want to have `N` consumers where `N` is the number of external locations I want to broadcast to. That should fulfill requirement (3). I also probably want one producer, my API, that will push events to my Kafka cluster. Requirement (2) should come in automatically with Kafka.

I was more confused regarding how to model the internal Kafka cluster side of things. Again, from the reading I did, it sounds like it's a bad practice to have millions of topics, so having a single topic for each `userID` is not an option. The other option I read about is having one partition for each `userID` (let's say `M` partitions). That would allow requirement (1) to happen out of the box, if I understand correctly. But that would also mean I have `M` brokers, is that correct? That also sounds unreasonable.

What would be the best way to fulfill all requirements? As a start, I plan on hosting this with a local Kafka cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that one topic per user is not ideal.

Partition count is not dependent upon broker count, so this is a better design.

> If a single external location is failing, that shouldn't delay delivery to other locations.

This is standard consumer-group behavior, not topic/partition design.

Comment: I see, so I could have a single broker (when running locally) with multiple partitions? Do I need to know the number of partitions when I create my Kafka cluster? I am thinking I won’t be able to know the number of users beforehand.

Comment: Clusters start with only internal topics. You are required to define the partition count when you create your own user-topics. The only limit per-broker is determined by open file-handles (I believe). You can increase the partition count later, however this will not "move/rebalance" data to the new partitions. If you want to key by user information, assuming they have numeric IDs, you could use 10 partitions and define a `mod 10` partitioner. 16 with a hexadecimal number, or 36 partitions with a single alphanumeric leading character, or 36^2 with leading two characters and so on.